# Codeigniter image upload and path to database

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, upload

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to make an upload form in codeigniter.
Not sure what I am doing wrong, everything else is getting correctly in the database. I looked in the documentation and tried several things but I'm not getting any further.. Any feedback is very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

model:

```
public function set_newstudent()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('naam'), 'dash', TRUE);

                 $config['upload_path'] = '/file_path/';
                 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                 $this->upload->data('full_path'););
                 $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();

                 $image = $data_upload_files[full_path];

                 $data = array(

            'naam' => $this->input->post('naam'),
            'voornaam' => $this->input->post('voornaam'),
            'id' => $slug,
            'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
            'picture'=>$this->input->post('picture')
    );

        return $this->db->insert('student', $data);
    }
```

controller:

```
public function create()
            {
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $data['title'] = 'Create a new Student';

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('naam', 'Naam', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('voornaam', 'Voornaam', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
                    {
                    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('students/create');
                    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

                    }
                else
                    {
                    $this->student_model->set_newstudent();
                    $this->load->view('students/success');
                    }
            }
```

view:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>


<?php echo form_open_multipart('student/create');?>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="naam">Naam</label><br>
<input type="input" name="naam" class="form-control" /><br />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="voornaam">Voornaam</label><br>
<input type="input" name="voornaam" class="form-control"/><br />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="text">Vertel iets over jezelf:</label><br>
<textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea><br />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="text">Kies een profiel foto:</label><br>
<input type="file" name="userfile"  class="btn btn-default btn-file" />

</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" 
value="Create student" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:1%" />

</form>
```

Comment: What is this ? `$this->upload->create`

Comment: Sorry sir my mistake, it should be $this->upload->data('full_path');

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using please ?

Comment: Code igniter version is 3.1.4

Comment: What are you trying to insert in the id column ?

Comment: in the picture column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i see, there is no

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

That's the function responsible for performing the upload and it's not there in your code,you may want to read this:
[File uploading Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller)

*UPDATE*

Your code should look something like this,

Controller:

```
public function create(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $data['title'] = 'Create a new Student';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('naam', 'Naam', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('voornaam', 'Voornaam', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('students/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }else{
        // Upload the files then pass data to your model
        $config['upload_path'] = '/file_path/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            // If the upload fails
            echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
        }else{
            // Pass the full path and post data to the set_newstudent model
            $this->student_model->set_newstudent($this->upload->data('full_path'),$this->input->post());
            $this->load->view('students/success');
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function set_newstudent($path,$post){ 
    $data = array( 
        'naam' => $post['naam'], 
        'voornaam' => $post['voornaam'], 
        'text' => $post['text'], 
        'picture'=>$path 
    ); 

    return $this->db->insert('student', $data); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.  Can I add this to the function create() ? or does it have to be a separate function?

Comment: There is no such function as create, can you tell me where did you find this function ?

Comment: In the controller

Comment: No you can't do that, you may want to re-write the code using the example i gave you in the documentation

Comment: I tried to implement the code following the tutorial in de codeigniter tutorial but i'm getting a bit confused, as my input from text fields gets into the database

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi Bounya for this code, but when I try this now I get reffered to a blank page instead of views/students/success.php and now no data is being posted in the database

Comment: Add the code i added `echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');`

Comment: Thank you Mehdi, I then get the error: The upload path does not appear to be valid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143629/discussion-between-mehdi-bounya-and-moya).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code where you are using upload library. You are using the wrong function to upload files. Below is the correct code:

```
        $config['upload_path'] = '/file_path/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // Check file uploaded or not
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();
            $image = $data_upload_files[full_path];
        } else {
            // possibly do some clean up ... then throw an error

        }
```

This code should work.

Comment: Sorry it's not working, I changed the code in the controller to the above but i'm still not getting the result

Comment: May I know what exact error you are getting on screen?

Comment: The thing is, I do not get an error. The user gets created and the fields First and Last name are being written in the database, but I see no picture even though it was attached